# Selenium - ElementNotVisibleException. Element is visible in Safari 9.1, but not in 10.1?

Tags: javascript, selenium, safari

This test:

```
@when('voter clicks "{b}"')
def step(context, b):
    context.browser.find_element_by_name(button).click()
```

Throws:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: An element command 
could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

So I added a

```
print(context.browser.find_element_by_name(button).is_displayed())
```

In Safari 9.1, it returns True, but in 10.1 it returns False.

What could be the reason for this when the HTML and JS is identical for both?

How could I get it to work in Safari 10?

e1:
Adding a wait didn't work:

```
element = WebDriverWait(context.browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, b))
)
```

Comment: Is the element always visible or is it shown from some kind of interaction? If it is shown from an interaction, you might be trying to access the element too early before that interaction is done so the element is not visible yet

Comment: I have the same issue, with safari 11.0.2. Super frustrating. How did you solve it?

Comment: Unsolvable so far

Answer (score 1):

On Yosemite Safari 10  is not included the Safari Driver, you should downgrade your selenium version 2.48.0 [Selenium version 2.48.0](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). Or update your OS to macOS Sierra [Read it here](https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/).

Or Update your version of Safari Driver to 10.0.2 beta 2.

Comment: "Or update your OS to macOS Sierra".  I have been testing this on Sierra. So shouldn't it work?

Comment: on Sierra you should see  Safari version as 11 and not 10.0.2 beta, check if all the updates are installed

Comment: That's on High Sierra, regular Sierra shows 10.1 as the latest.

Comment: I'm using browserstack to test actually https://www.browserstack.com/start . IDK how that affects the webdriver versions

Comment: lot of safaridriver bug fixes are in safari 11 and its much stable